# PHP re-order values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like the following:

```
$content = array(array("id_post" => 1000, "id_user" => 4),
                 array("id_post" => 1001, "id_user" => 4),
                 array("id_post" => 1002, "id_user" => 3),
                 array("id_post" => 1003, "id_user" => 4),
                 array("id_post" => 1004, "id_user" => 5),
                 array("id_post" => 1005, "id_user" => 5));
```

So it means `5 => 1004, 1005` and `4 => 1000, 1001, 1003` and `3 => 1002`.

First, how do I get this structure? (possible with commas)

My algorithm for this solution would be something like (here's what I'm asking you guys..how to accomplish this):

```
$arr = array();
for($i = 0; $i <= count($content) - 1; $i++){
   if exists key ($content[$i]['id_user']) IN $arr then
      $arr = add_to_existing_key "," . $content[$i]['id_post']
   } other wise {
      $arr = add_new_key PLUS value $content[$i]['id_user'] <=> $content[$i]['id_post']
   }
}
```

I need the commas so I could parse the info later.
Basically, the objective of this is to do a loop with `$arr` variable. Imagining that the array would have, finally, something like:

```
("id_user" => 5, "ids" => '1004,1005'),
("id_user" => 4, "ids" => '1000,1001,1003'),
("id_user" => 3, "ids" => '1002')

for($i = 0; $i <= count($arr) - 1; $i++){
    $ids = explode(",", $arr[$i]['ids']);

    $info = array();

    for($y = 0; $y <= count($ids) - 1; $y++){
        $query->("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $ids[$y]");
        $info[] = array($name, $description);
    }

    $email->sendEmail($info); // id = 5 => info OF 1004, 1005
    $info = array();          // clear array
                              // loop
                              // id = 4 => info OF 1000, 1001, 1003
                              // loop etc
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr = array();
// Loop through each content
foreach ($content as $post)
{
  $arr[$post['id_user']][] = $post['id_post'];
}
```

This way, the result would be

```
$arr = array(
  '5'=> array('1004', '1005'),
  '4'=> array('1000', '1001', '1003'),
  '3'=> array('1002')
);
```

Then you won't need to use "explode" just to split those comma-separated IDs
Also

Comment: Perfect. Just to complete the answer, to access those values: `foreach($arr as $key => $post){
     echo $key . "<br/>";
}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be better off sticking with arrays instead of joining on commas and then `exploding` later:

```
foreach($content as $values) {
    if(!isset($result[$values['id_user']])) {
        $result[$values['id_user']] = array();
    }
    array_push($result[$values['id_user']], $values['id_post']);
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this variant will be exactly what you need:

```
$content = array(array("id_post" => 1000, "id_user" => 4),
    array("id_post" => 1002, "id_user" => 3),
    array("id_post" => 1004, "id_user" => 5),
    array("id_post" => 1003, "id_user" => 4),
    array("id_post" => 1001, "id_user" => 4),
    array("id_post" => 1005, "id_user" => 5));

// Make preparation array
foreach ( $content as $values ) {
    if ( !isset($result[$values['id_user']]) ) {
        $result[$values['id_user']] = array();
    }
    array_push($result[$values['id_user']], $values['id_post']);
}

// Sort inner arrays
foreach ( $result as $key => $valueArray ) {
    asort($result[$key]);
}

// Implode arrays to strings
array_walk($result, function(&$array, $key) {
            $array = implode(',', $array);
        });

// Final array
$result1 = array();
foreach ( $result as $userID => $idsString ) {
    $result1[] = array("id_user" => $userID, "id_post" => $idsString);
}

print_r($result1);
```